# Reverse name task

Tags: java

Here is what my code is trying to do:
Write a method called processName that accepts a Scanner for the console as a parameter and prompts the user to
enter a full name, then prints the name in reverse order (i.e., last name, first name).

**Here is an example dialogue with the user:**

> Please enter your full name: Sammy Jankis
>
> Your name in reverse order is Jankis, Sammy

```
import java.util.*; 
public class Project3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Please enter your full name: ");
        String firstname = console.next();
        String lastname = console.next();
        processName(firstname, lastname);
    }

    public static void processName(String y, String z) {
        System.out.print("Your name in reverse order is"
             + z + ", " + y);               
    }
}
```

I get an error reading:

```
Project3.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable console
location: class Project3
        String firstname = console.next();
                           ^
Project3.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable console
location: class Project3
        String lastname = console.next();
                          ^
```

My question is, how can I divide the name string into two parts so that I can reverse it? Please use simple terms because I am new to coding.

Comment: You did not define `console`. Look into setting up a `Scanner` on `System.In`. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to declare (and initialize) `console`. I think you wanted

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
```

before `String firstname = console.next();`

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved it. I'm not sure how to close this thread but my question has been answered.

Comment: Oh I see, I'll just wait 10 minutes to click that checkmark.

Comment: @JimmyGuo [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/243725) I also suggest you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).